# How can I validate a post request from an raw HTML form (No django form used)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
def update(request, property_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(PropertyModel, property_id=
    form = PropertyModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    template = 'form.html'
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

have done using Django model from but want to do it using HTML form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use Django forms but if that's not an option you can go ahead and use Javascript and manually checking on the views, here's an extremely rough 
example.

html form

```
<form action="{% url 'some-url' %}" method='post'>
    <input type="email" id='email' name='email'>
    <input type='password' id='passowrd' name='password'>
    <button type="button" onclick="Validate()">submit</button>
</form>
```

java script validation

```
function validate(){
    if ($("#email").val() == ""){
        alert("email field is required");
    }   
    if ($("#password").val().length < 8){
        alert("password should be over 8 characters");
    }   
}
```

behind the scenes views

```
from validate_email import validate_email

def myview(request):
   email = request.POST.get('email') 
   password = request.POST.get('password')

   if validate_email(email):
      if len(password) > 8:
        print("both the conditions met")
      else:
        messages.error("password should be over 8 characters")
        return redirect("url")
    else:
        messages.error("valid email is required")
        return redirect("url")
```