# Validating views.py

Tags: python, django, validation

Can someone advice me how to prevent to 'POST' empty form? i think im missing: if form.is_valid()... but im too noob and dont know where to implement it...

```
def addContact(request):

    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # form = Contact(
            # full_name = request.POST ('fullname'),
            # relationship = request.POST ('relationship'),
            # email = request.POST ('email'),
            # phone_number = request.POST ('phone-number'),
            # address = request.POST ('address'),
            # )
            form.save()
        return redirect('/contact')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'contact/new.html', context)


def contactProfile(request,pk):
    contact = Contact.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'contact/contact-profile.html', {'contact': contact})
```

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Contact

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Contact(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    phone_number =models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Comment: Use `request.POST.get("item")` instead of `request.POST["item"]` because if something is not in the `request.POST` dictionary (like `fullname` is not send with the request so it is not inside ) you will get an exception.

Comment: Can you add your forms.py ?

Comment: i didnt evene created forms.py. for this app.

Comment: So where does your form come from ?

Comment: from the models

Comment: Can you just add the form in your question so i have a clear idea of what you're talking about ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3d0yLialDo this my tutorial on what i was basic on. I finalised this project but when i was testing it. I just added 'blank' contact and it was looking very bad in there, thats why I was trying to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track.

If you put the `if form.is_valid():` inside your `if request.method == 'POST'`

then it should do what you are looking for.

So this should be the code:

```
def addContact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST) # Edit made here, you need to define the form you are using from your forms.py
        if form.is_valid():
            new_contact = Contact(
            full_name = request.POST ['fullname'],
            relationship = request.POST ['relationship'],
            email = request.POST ['email'],
            phone_number = request.POST ['phone-number'],
            address = request.POST ['address'],
        )
        new_contact.save()
        return redirect('/contact')
    return render(request, 'contact/new.html')
```

---

Edit:

It is also good practice to include an else in the request.method if statement.

Another good practice is to use `form.cleaned_data.get()` for passing your data.

Example:

```
def getData(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data = form.cleaned_data.get('dataField')
```

Comment: im receiving " name 'form' is not defined"

Comment: Your answer is not right, form is an unknown variable and there is no point in creating an instance direcly from the Model if you use a form.

Comment: That is right, I did not mention that you have to define the form first. I will make an edit. You need to define the form you are using before the if statement `if form.is_valid()` so whatever form is being used should be defined there.

Comment: @ArturJasiński Please see the edit in my post.

Comment: That's gonna work now but it's still bad code... use your form to save, not the model... @Shyrtle

Comment: I was not aware that this was a bad practice. I thought this was using the form to save it. Would you mind explaining why this is bad? (I am currently using this method in a few projects) @BriseBalloches

Comment: i didnt evene created forms.py. for this app.

Comment: One of the goal of forms is basically to save/update an object and you do this with `form.save()`. In that way, you can create custom behaviour while saving and you keep that code overriding save method and that keeps your view clean from too much code.

Comment: @ArturJasiński I think you will need to create a forms.py in that case. You can check the django documentation on how to do that. But if there isn't a form, I don't know of a way to validate the data. You could try validating the data with javascript, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486180/how-can-i-validate-a-post-request-from-an-raw-html-form-no-django-form-used

Comment: @BriseBalloches So are you saying to not use the `form.cleaned_data` because using `form.save()` should be making those distinctions in the forms.py?

Comment: That depends on your situation but if you have a ModelForm that just creates an instance then yes it should all be in your forms.py and then just call save() from your views.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative would be add a required attribute on your HTML inputs but that might not help everytime since the user could just remove it from the Inspect tab and submit an empty form LOL. Just use the form.is_valid or just tryna check if the fields are empty using:

```
if full_name == null OR relationship == null OR email == null OR phone_number == null OR address == null:
    #Some Return an error statement
```

Hope that helps! (: